# VAO not rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I made a loader class for loading V.A.Os textures etc but when i use this method

```
GLuint Loader::loadToVAO(GLfloat* vertices)
{
    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    return vertexbuffer;
}
```

it doesnt render anything here is my render code:

```
window.createWindow();

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};

GLuint vertexbuffer = loader.loadToVAO(vertices);

glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 0);

// It works fine when i generate the vao in the main method but not in the loader class
GLuint vertexbuffer1;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

std::cout << vertexbuffer1 << std::endl;
std::cout << vertexbuffer << std::endl;

while (!window.shouldClose())
{
    window.clearWindow();

    // render here
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );
    // Draw the triangle !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    window.updateWindow();
}

return 0;
```

it renders fine when i try to render the `vertexbuffer1` (the one loaded in the main method) but the vertexbuffer doesn't render anything.
any help would be appreciated

**EDIT:**
here is the tutorial im trying to follow - http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `sizeof` on a pointer type inside your function, which is almost certainly not what you want. Arrays are not [first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in languages like C and C++, they decay to pointers, which do not carry the information about the amount of data that they store. What you want to do instead is to pass the size of the array as an additional argument:

```
GLuint Loader::loadToVAO(GLfloat* vertices, size_t num_vertices)
{
    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(*vertices) * num_vertices, vertices, 
    GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    return vertexbuffer;
}
```

And then in your main function:

```
GLuint vertexbuffer = loader.loadToVAO(vertices, sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]));
```

I'd encourage you to read more about the topic [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/40783/).

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH MAN!! IVE BEEN STRUGGLING FOR DAYS THANKS SO MUCH